# Unable to assign function return value with destructuring assignment

Tags: python, pandas, destructuring

I'd like to split a letter and a number in a function, return both values and assign them to variables using destructuring assignment as follows:

```
def split_string(str):
    if str is not np.nan:
        match = re.search("(\w{1})(\d{1,3})", str)
        if match is not None:
            return match.group(0), match.group(1)
    return None, None
```

The function returns the desired results, e.g.:

```
0      (None, None)
1           (C, 85)
2      (None, None)
3          (C, 123)
```

But if I try to assign the results I get a ValueError (`data` is a Pandas DataFrame from CSV and `data.strings` is a column of strings and NaN's):

```
a, b = data.strings.apply(split_string)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-40dc67dc859d> in <module>()
      6     return None, None
      7 
----> 8 a, b = data.strings.apply(split_string)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

However, this works fine:

```
def test(x, y):
    return x, y

a, b = test(1, 2)
```

What am I missing here? I'd really like to be able to process and assign return values for the whole column in one line. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are returning a `Series` of tuples. What happens when you unpack as a single object?

Comment: It would help if you post part of the data

Comment: `split_string` might return a 2-tuple, but that doesn't mean `apply` does.

Comment: Also, your error message comes from different code, where you're using `split_cabin`.

Comment: @spies006 I get the same list of tuples as in the second code block in the question.

Comment: @basse and you say that is your desired output. So problem solved?

Comment: @spies006 well, yes, the elements are what I want, but then I need to assign them to two new separate columns in the original `data` DataFrame, which is what I'm unable to do (in one line as attempted).

Comment: @basse ah I see, I think I have that solution. I'm not sure if it will translate to your own data but it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a sample data frame with a `Series` of strings as described.

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'strings': ['the', 'test', 'data', np.nan, 'end']})

>>> a = data.strings.apply(split_string)
>>> a
0    (None, None)
1    (None, None)
2    (None, None)
3    (None, None)
4    (None, None)
```

If you want to create two new columns in one line you can use `zip`.

```
>>> a, b = zip(*data.strings.apply(split_string))
>>> a
(None, None, None, None, None)
>>> b
(None, None, None, None, None)
```

We can assign them directly to `data` as new columns in one line.

```
>>> data['a'], data['b'] = zip(*data.strings.apply(split_string))
>>> data
  string     a     b
0    the  None  None
1   test  None  None
2   data  None  None
3    NaN  None  None
4    end  None  None
```

Comment: The `zip` solution is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you! I tried applying `zip` in the function (split_string) when returning values, which obviously didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply returns a series or data frame.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html